# Java code not working - don't know the source of the error?

Tags: java

I am making a quiz with Java, and an error has appeared. When I enter in the *right* answer, it says it is wrong. Any ideas?

Code:

```
package revision_project;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Quiz {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] questions = {"What is an integer?", "What does CPU stand for?", "How far can a LAN go?",
                "What does LAN stand for?", "Give an example of a WAN.", "What is a syntax error?"};
        String[] answers = {"a whole number", "central processing unit", "2km", "local area network",
                "internet", "when the programmer enters in incorrect syntax."};
        List<String> correct = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
            System.out.println(questions[i] + ": " + newline);
            String x = input.nextLine();
            x = x.toLowerCase();

            if(x == answers[i]){
                System.out.println("Correct");
                //correct.add("Correct");
            } else{
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                //correct.add("Wrong");
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: use String.equals() for string comparison

Comment: Yes I can, "..and an error has appeared"? So, what's the error?

Comment: This part. >When I enter in the right answer, it says it is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @rtharper Have you read the question I linked to?

Comment: @Perneel He wrote the "error" (I think he means bug) right after mentioning it. So instead of just writing unconstructive comments, you could try and correct his post with an edit?

Comment: I was expecting a stack trace when I saw 'error'. That was what I was referring to. Anyway, it's clear to me now. The 'unconstructive comment' was in a reaction to the blunt answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you compare `String`s by using their `equals(String str)` method:

```
 if(x.equals(answers[i])) {
     System.out.println("Correct");
 } else {
     System.out.println("Wrong");
 }
```